# Why doesn't my Do While loop stop after the condition is not met?

Tags: java, switch-statement, boolean, do-while

I have written a code which gets user's input on the start dates & the end dates and checks if they are valid. In the code below, I have 2 do..while loops. One is for start date and the other is for end date. When the first loop is executed and the condition is not met, the program doesn't move on to the other do while loop. It would be helpful if I could receive solutions for this problem.

```
int year, startMonth, endMonth, startDay, endDay; 
    boolean checkStartDate = false, checkEndDate = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //checking Start Date
    do
    {   
    checkStartDate = false;
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
    year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the start month: ");
    startMonth = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the start day: ");
    startDay = input.nextInt(); 

        switch (startMonth) 
        {
          case 1:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
          break;

          case 2:
       if(startDay <= 28)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 3:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }

            break;

          case 4:
        if(startDay <= 30)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 5:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 6:
        if(startDay <= 30)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 7:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 8:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 9:
        if(startDay <= 30)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 10:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 11:
        if(startDay <= 30)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 12:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
            return;     
        }
          default:
          checkStartDate = false;
          System.out.println("Try again and enter a valid date \n");
        }   
        checkStartDate = false;

    } while (checkStartDate = true);

    //checking End Date

    do
    {   
    checkEndDate = false;
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
    year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the start month: ");
    endMonth = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the start day: ");
    endDay = input.nextInt(); 

        switch (endMonth) 
        {
          case 1:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }

        else
        {
            checkEndDate = false;
            System.out.println("Print a valid start day");
        }
          break;

          case 2:
       if(endDay <= 28)
        {
           checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 3:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }

            break;

          case 4:
        if(endDay <= 30)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 5:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 6:
        if(endDay <= 30)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 7:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 8:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 9:
        if(endDay <= 30)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 10:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 11:
        if(endDay <= 30)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 12:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
            return;
        }

          default:
            checkEndDate = false;
            System.out.println("Try again and enter a valid date \n");
        }   
        checkEndDate = false;

    } while (checkEndDate = true);

    System.out.println("correct ");
```

Comment: Just a heads up: once you get this working and have complete, runnable code, you can post this over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) and we can help you write cleaner code (like improving the giant `switch`es).

Answer (score 2):

```
while (checkEndDate = true)
```

You are **assigning** `checkEndDate` to be true, so the loop will always repeat. You probably meant:

```
while (checkEndDate == true)
```

This **compares** two values. But since you already have a boolean, you don't need the comparison:

```
while (checkEndDate)
```

Note that you can significantly reduce the amount of code by combining similar cases. For example:

```
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
    if(startDay <= 31)
    {
        checkStartDate = true;
    }
    break;
```

The same for the months with 30 days.

You should also write a `checkDate()` method so that you don't have the same code written twice.

Answer (score 0):

you added  `checkStartDate= false & checkEndDate = false;` end of each do while loop. which is not required.

Update the while condition as `while (checkStartDate);` as its evaluate with Boolean value.

below is the working code

int year, startMonth, endMonth, startDay, endDay; 
        boolean checkStartDate = false, checkEndDate = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

```
    //checking Start Date
    do
    {   
    checkStartDate = false;
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
    year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the start month: ");
    startMonth = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the start day: ");
    startDay = input.nextInt(); 

        switch (startMonth) 
        {
          case 1:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
          break;

          case 2:
       if(startDay <= 28)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 3:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }

            break;

          case 4:
        if(startDay <= 30)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 5:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 6:
        if(startDay <= 30)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 7:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 8:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 9:
        if(startDay <= 30)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 10:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 11:
        if(startDay <= 30)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 12:
        if(startDay <= 31)
        {
            checkStartDate = true;
            return;     
        }
          default:
          checkStartDate = false;
          System.out.println("Try again and enter a valid date \n");
        }   
       // checkStartDate = false;

    } while (checkStartDate);

    //checking End Date

    do
    {   
    checkEndDate = false;
    System.out.print("Check End Date... ");
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
    year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the start month: ");
    endMonth = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the start day: ");
    endDay = input.nextInt(); 

        switch (endMonth) 
        {
          case 1:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }

        else
        {
            checkEndDate = false;
            System.out.println("Print a valid start day");
        }
          break;

          case 2:
       if(endDay <= 28)
        {
           checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 3:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }

            break;

          case 4:
        if(endDay <= 30)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 5:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 6:
        if(endDay <= 30)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 7:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 8:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 9:
        if(endDay <= 30)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 10:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 11:
        if(endDay <= 30)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
        }
            break;

          case 12:
        if(endDay <= 31)
        {
            checkEndDate = true;
            return;
        }

          default:
            checkEndDate = false;
            System.out.println("Try again and enter a valid date \n");
        }   
      //  checkEndDate = false; 

    } while (checkEndDate);

    System.out.println("correct ");
```